# Use Data in Textarea and Pass it On as Variable in Play 2.1

Tags: javascript, html, playframework-2.1

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm having some syntax issues. I have two `textarea`. After the user inputs the information in the `textarea`, he/she will press the `execute-button` and it should pass those two data in the `textarea` to a `controller` for some data processing. I am using the Play 2.1 framework. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    <h2>First Serial</h2>
    <textarea id="firstSerial" style="width:600px;height:50px"></textarea><br/>

    <h2>Second Serial</h2>
    <textarea id="secondSerial" style="width:600px;height:50px"></textarea><br/><br/>

    <script>
        function grabTheSerials() {
            var firstSerial = document.getElementById('firstSerial').value;
            var secondSerial = document.getElementById('secondSerial').value;

            location.href="@routes.App.function(" + firstSerial + ", " + secondSerial + ")";
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="execute-button" onclick="grabTheSerials()"/>
```

The code doesn't actually pass the variable through. I did the console debug and it actually literally just passes `+firstSerial+`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Play template language with Javascript.  The template language is compiled, so I don't believe putting javascript variables into a compiled route method will work as you want it to.  Why not just POST the data to a controller to handle the processing?

Comment: That was the first thing that came to my mind; mixing play with JS. But I did a little experiment by hardcoding the serial numbers instead and it processed fine in the controller. So it seems like JS is working fine with Play.

Comment: It would be a lot easier, safer and more reliable to probably just POST the data to a controller like in my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend you do, if I understand your question correctly.

For the HTML form:

```
<form method='post' action='@routes.App.function()'>
<h2>First Serial</h2>
    <textarea name="firstSerial" id="firstSerial"\ rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>

    <h2>Second Serial</h2>
    <textarea name="secondSerial" id="secondSerial" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="execute-button" />
</form>
```

Then, in a Play controller, do something like this:

```
  public static Result function(){
        RequestBody body = request().body();
        Map<String, String[]> f = body.asFormUrlEncoded();
        String serial1 = f.get("firstSerial")[0];
        String serial2 = f.get("secondSerial")[0];
     //Do something with serial1 and serial2, like redirect to a new controller,
     //render a custom template, save in a database, or process
     //any other way you need.
}
```

or this:

```
public static Result function(){
     DynamicForm dynamicForm = DynamicForm.form().bindFromRequest();
     String serial1 = dynamicForm.get("firstSerial");
     String serial2 = dynamicForm.get("secondSerial");
     //Do something with serial1 and serial2, like redirect to a new controller,
     //render a custom template, save in a database, or process
     //any other way you need.
    }
```

Make sure your `routes` file is set up for this, too:

`POST      /function      controllers.App.function()`

Comment: Is there a way to make RequestBody and DynamicForm not show up as errors? I tried import play.data.DynamicForm; but it still has compile error.

EDIT: Oops never mind I had another error before it.

Comment: Sounds good, glad you got it working.  Also - no need to use both RequestBody and DynamicForm in the same controller method, it would be redundant.

Comment: Actually I'm getting null values for both methods for serial1 and serial2

Comment: I got it working. For some reason <textarea> isn't compatible or something. So I used <input> and it works.

Comment: That's weird, it should work exactly as shown.  Try adding a "name" value to the textareas perhaps?  I changed my example to reflect how to do that. If the solution above works for you, please consider selecting the response as an answer.  Thank you!